# How to synchronise a folder from GitHub repository branch upon commit to a Dropbox directory?

Tags: github, dropbox, synchronization, zapier

I have a GitHub repository with multiple branches that I and others regularly commit to, but I'm only interested in the `master` branch here. Whenever this is committed to, I want to sync new and changed (or deleted) files with a public Dropbox folder. This only needs to work in one direction. It would be nice, but not required, if it could be limited to a particular folder in the GitHub repository.

I have found solutions to do this with local Git repositories, but I want it to work without needing a particular workstation to be up and running. I looked at the GitHub Marketplace, IFTTT, Zapier and, of course, Google but found no ready-made solution. (Zapier only has a workflow for the opposite direction, passing files new on Dropbox to GitHub commits.)

Zapier can watch a GitHub repository for commits as a *trigger* and upload a file to Dropbox as an *action*, but I don't see how any of the fields provided by the GitHub API could be turned into an appropriate URL for the Dropbox API. I could add intermediate *filter* and *action* steps at Zapier, but I don't see which would be useful.

Is there a way to achieve this using Zapier?

Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried: https://github.com/anishathalye/git-remote-dropbox ?

> A transparent bridge between Git and Dropbox - use a Dropbox (shared) folder as a Git remote!